# Massless Kerr black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

Kerr metric has the following form:

$$
ds^2 = -\left(1 - \frac{2GMr}{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}\right) dt^2 +
       \left(\frac{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}{r^2-2GMr+a^2}\right) dr^2 +
    \left(r^2+a^2\cos(\theta)\right) d\theta^2 
  + \left(r^2+a^2+\frac{2GMra^2}{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}\right)\sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2 -
    \left(\frac{4GMra\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}\right) d\phi\, dt
$$

This metric describes a rotating black hole.

If one considers $M=0$:

$$
ds^2 = - dt^2 +
       \left(\frac{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}{r^2+a^2}\right) dr^2 +
    \left(r^2+a^2\cos(\theta)\right) d\theta^2 
  +
    \left(r^2+a^2\right)\sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2 
$$

This metric is a solution of the Einstein equations in vacuum.

**What is the  physical interpretation of such a solution?**

Comment: See page 15 of [this review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0622.pdf).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's simply flat space in [Boyer-Lindquist coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates?wprov=sfla1). By writing

$\begin{cases}
x=\sqrt{r^2+a^2}\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
y=\sqrt{r^2+a^2}\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z=r\cos\theta
\end{cases}$

you'll get good ol' $\mathbb{M}^4$.

Comment: Note also that these coordinates are related to [oblate spheroidal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroidal_coordinates) by the simple substitution $r = a \sinh \mu$ and $\theta = \pi/2 - \nu$.

Answer (score 15):

This is presumably a flat spacetime described in funny coordinates. You can check this by calculating the Riemann tensor to see if it's zero. If I was going to do this, I would code it in the open-source computer algebra system Maxima, using the ctensor package.

Comment: I disagree with the “not an answer” flags and comments. Partial answers are still answers. This is essentially the same as the accepted answer, except with a nudge towards an analysis technique rather than the name of the solution.

Comment: Here's how it's done in Mathematica, all the relevant tensors and scalars show the flat spacetime: [Kerr with M=0](http://relativity.yukterez.net/81.html)

Answer (score 3):

A reference which answers this is [Visser (2008)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0622). It discusses the limits of vanishing mass $M \rightarrow 0$, and rotation parameter $a \rightarrow 0$. Your example is in $\S5$. Visser comments "This is flat Minkowski space in so-called “oblate spheroidal” coordinates...", as described in a different answer here.